# python list comprehension vs. *operation of list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Now I'm refactoring some code and I found something weird.

I thought the following 2 expressions were exactly same:

```
list1 = [[0.00] * 5 for _ in range(5)]
list2 = [[0.00] * 5] * 5
```

I can see they make same results by running:

```
print(list1 == list2)
```

or

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(list1).shape == np.array(list2).shape)
```

But in the project I'm revising, `list2` doesn't work. When I use it, it raises 'Index out of range'.

Please tell me if 'list1 == list2' as I said, or if I'm wrong about that.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I can use `numpy.zeros()` or some other things, but I'm really curious.

Comment: You do not want to use the second approach, it creates 5 references to the same list

Comment: They're equal, but they won't behave the same. Also you don't show a [mcve] of the code that errors.

Comment: Since they _are_ equal, there’s a good chance the error you’re encountering is related to code not shown in the question. For example, they would behave differently if the sublists are mutated.

Comment: To see the difference, compare the results of `map(id, list1)` and `map(id, list2)`. (Or `list(map(id, list1))` and `list(map(id, list2))` if you are using Python 3.)